# Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID error message

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

So I am trying to upload for testing, and I see this error in Google Play Console:

```
Error
Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.

If you don't include this permission in your manifest file, your advertising identifier will be zeroed out. This may break your advertising and analytics use cases, and cause loss of revenue. Learn more

You can remove these errors by updating your advertising ID declaration

Apps that target Android 13 (API 33) without the AD_ID permission will have their advertising identifier zeroed out. This may impact advertising and analytics use-cases. Learn more
```

So I updated it and selected YES on **This includes any SDKs that your app imports that use advertising ID**. Also selected **Advertising or marketing**
[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO5Cg.png)

I open up my project in Android Studio, open up **AndroidManifest.xml** and add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
```

When I rebuild, and upload the new **app-release.aab** file, I still get that same error.

Why do I keep getting this error message? (I know in the "This is what it looks like" part I can select "Turn off release errors", but the message will still be there as a warning.)

Comment: "A manifest file in **one of your active artifacts**" - is the error because of an existing artifact you need to delete from the Play Store somewhere? (rather than being about the new aab you uploaded)

Comment: @TylerV Then how do I know what app this is for if I have multiple apps?

Comment: I'm not saying it's for a different app - there is an artifact library for each app and the message sounds like it could be referring to an active artifact (e.g. the one active for alpha testing or internal testing or something) rather than the one you uploaded. Ultimately, I don't think anyone is really going to provide you with much more than that here. You need to contact Google help if you need help with the Play Store.

Comment: Unfortunately Google has made it impossible to delete old artifacts without uploading new ones, which puts you in this perpetual loop of failure.